# Selecting a combobox item resets the entire form

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHlAy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIz47.png)
problem 1 :
codes reset the whole form. only need to reset the combobox
actually in this part `Application.Restart();`
i need a similar code

```
this.Controls.Clear();
InitializeComponent();
```

problem 2 :
The combobox doesn't show the selected language automatically either. When the program is opened, it comes as an empty combobox. I guess I want to take advantage of the startindex feature here, I'm not sure.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
                    break;
                    
         }
            

           
            this.Controls.Clear();
            InitializeComponent();
```

Waiting for your answers, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mentioning the problems with a form, but you have not shared the form itself.

Comment: You are also not providing some context or expected behavior

Comment: Update your code to include the part where your combo box items are being populated, are you using an array to populate it or custom objects?

Comment: I added languages ​​listed one under the other to the item collection, and at the same time, I select and write the item language text part one by one.

Comment: is best to improve the question, than to answer in the comments.

Comment: delegate the code that populates your comb box to a method and then call that method from the Form Loaded event handler so that the combo box is not empty when the application is loaded.

Comment: Also the line `Controls.Clear()` could be the problem, try commenting it out and try to click on an item

Comment: Who flagged this as a duplicate? Did he read the title of this post and the one he linked? What is stackoverflow coming to these days?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are resetting the form with this line of code inside the event handler that is triggered when the selected index of the form changes

```
this.Controls.Clear();
```

Try removing or commenting out that line and try to change the combo box item so that your new method looks similar to the method below

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
                    break;
                    
         }
}
```

As for your combo box being empty when the form is loaded then you can define a method that populates your combo box and call it from the Form  Loaded event handler.

```
//inside the constructor of your form, register the event handler that is triggered when the form is loaded
public MyForm{

Load += OnLoad;
}
//then in the Load event handler fill the combo box
private void OnLoad(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
      FillComboBox();
}
void FillComboBox(){
   var items = new string[]{"English","French","Chinese","Hindi"};
   foreach(var item in items){
    //assuming you have a definition for the combo box
    comboBox.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

Comment: When I fully implement this, the languages ​​come out in pairs. At the same time, the languages ​​Do not Change when I Click. The problem here is this.Controls.Clear();

Comment: If the form is not resetting anymore then problem 1 is solved, Can you update your post to include more information on the language array you are using to populate the combo box and how you are instantiating the combo box